# concatenate character vector elements while adding a "+" between the elements

Tags: r, concatenation

I need help with a function in R that allows me to go from:

```
vector <- c("a","b","c","d")
```

to

```
needed_result <- "y ~ a + b + c + d"
```

Thanks !

Comment: `paste("y ~", paste(vector, collapse = " + "))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to create a formula from `vector`, you can do it directly with `reformulate`:

```r
reformulate(vector, "y")
#> y ~ a + b + c + d
```